# Promise.all get put function as parameter with values

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

Im using the following code that work OK,

```
var aa = createA(val, 1000);
var bb = createB(val2, 500);


Promise.all([aa, bb])
  .spread(function(v1, v2) {
    console.log("im Here")
  }).catch(function() {
      aa.cancel()
```

Now when I need to do something inside the promise with aa I can like `aa.cancel();` etc , the problem now Is that I need to change it to be like 
following and lets say Im inside loop and need to get values inside so how can I do the **cancel now inside the catch**?

```
Promise.all([createA(val, 1000), bb])
      .spread(function(v1, v2) {
        console.log("im Here")
      }).catch(function() {
```

Comment: You can't cancel a Promise for which you have no reference for. Just like you can't call methods on an object for which you have no reference for.

Comment: just create it the same way, but make sure you take into consideration loops and closure

Comment: @JaromandaX -  Can you please provide example as answer?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - but assume I need to pass paramter to this promise all (I've spread before which provided value and after I do promise all...),how should I overcome this?

Comment: Most of all, you cannot cancel a promise that has already settled.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of the "loop" you refer to I can only speculate

If you had a simple for loop, this would not work as expected, due to the asynchronous nature of Promises

> **To be clear, don't do it like this**

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
    var aa = createA(val, 1000);
    var bb = createB(val2, 500);


    Promise.all([aa, bb])
    .spread(function(v1, v2) {
        console.log("im Here")
    }).catch(function() {
        aa.cancel()
    });
}
```

You'd need a closure - something like an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
    var aa = createA(val, 1000);
    var bb = createB(val2, 500);

    (function(a, b) {
        Promise.all([a, b])
        .spread(function(v1, v2) {
            console.log("im Here")
        }).catch(function() {
            a.cancel()
        });
    }(aa, bb));
}
```

or simply, create a function outside the loop and call it

```
function dothings(a, b) {
    Promise.all([a, b])
    .spread(function(v1, v2) {
        console.log("im Here")
    }).catch(function() {
        a.cancel()
    });
}

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
    var aa = createA(val, 1000);
    var bb = createB(val2, 500);

    dothings(aa, bb);
}
```

> If you show some more concrete example of what you want to achieve, I can edit the answer to target the specifics if this doesn't help

Comment: Btw, you missed it too: replace `aa` with `a` inside `dothings`. :)

Comment: yeah, I originally had aa, bb in the IIFE and the dothings as the argument names, but changed to a, b to make it clearer - and forgot to change them all :p